# google.chrome.storage undefined output

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I got this weird output from chrome.storage

When I tried this code here

```
var local;
chrome.storage.local.get(function(data) {
    local = data;
    console.log(local);
});
console.log('>');
console.log(local);
console.log('<');
```

Here's the output (dataString is the value of data)

```
>
undefined
<
dataString
```

To which the dataString should be printed before the > undefined < right? or maybe I am just confused

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Similar questions have been asked many times :), take a look at above link, about asynchronous call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says in [chrome storage docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), chrome.storage is asynchronous, so the callback function from `chrome.storage.local.get` executes later and that is why you get that output.